# Stretching background to 100% in firefox

Tags: image, firefox, browser, background, stretch

I am currently working with a javascript background script that changes the background on a timer and and in reference to day and night this works great but I'm trying to make the background stretch to 100% of the browser width, I've done this through CSS. It works in safari and chrome but not firefox (maybe IE too) instead it see's the 100% as showing the image at 100% of it's size, can anybody help?

I'm not sure if there is a hack to work with body or I'll have to rewrite the javascript to a div or something but not sure how, so any help is appreciated!

The javascript

```
    <script language="JavaScript1.2">

//Specify background images to slide
var bgslides=new Array()

var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
if (9 <= currentTime && currentTime < 18) {
   bgslides[0]="images/webcam1.jpg"
   bgslides[1]="images/webcam2.jpg"
   bgslides[2]="images/webcam3.jpg"
}
else
{
   bgslides[0]="images/webcamnight.jpg"
   bgslides[1]="images/webcamnight.jpg"
   bgslides[2]="images/webcamnight.jpg"
}

//Specify interval between slide (in miliseconds)
var speed=5000

//preload images
var processed=new Array()
for (i=0;i<bgslides.length;i++){
processed[i]=new Image()
processed[i].src=bgslides[i]
}

var inc=-1

function slideback(){
if (inc<bgslides.length-1)
inc++
else
inc=0
document.body.background=processed[inc].src
}

if (document.all||document.getElementById)
window.onload=new Function('setInterval("slideback()",speed)')
window.onload=new Function('setInterval("slideback()",speed)')

</script>
```

and the css

```
  body{

background-position: 0 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 100%


}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
background-size: cover;
```

or

```
background-size: 100% cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size: 100% 100%; /* w3 spec - no browser supports it yet */
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%; /* used for firefox */
-o-background-size: 100% 100%; /* used for opera */
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%; /* used for safari and chrome */
```

Comment: Tried that before, just did again, doesn't work, no idea why, I know it's the standard hack, I'm not sure if it being in the body tag is interfearing...

Answer (score 0):

While this property is new in Gecko 1.9.2 (Firefox 3.6), it is possible to stretch a image fully over the background in Firefox 3.5 by using -moz-border-image .

```
    .foo {
           background-image: url(bg-image.png);

           -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;         /* Gecko 1.9.2 (Firefox 3.6) */
           -o-background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Opera 9.5 */
           -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;      /* Safari 3.0 */
           background-size: 100% 100%;              /* Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4.0) and other CSS3-compliant browsers */

           -moz-border-image: url(bg-image.png) 0;  /* Gecko 1.9.1 (Firefox 3.5) */
    }
```

You can also try to fake stretching a background:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
       <head>
           <title>Stretched image in background</title>

           <style type="text/css">
              body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
              #bgimg { position:absolute; z-index:-1; width:100%; height:100% }
           </style>

      </head>
      <body>

         <img id="bgimg" src="http://www.lcvm.nl/images/nieuwsbrief/illusie2.gif" />
         <!-- content will go here -->

      </body>
  </html>
```

By way of dom you can change the img.

Comment: doesn't work, I'm not sure if it's because I'm not specifyng the background in the css maybe? it's in a javascript function.

Comment: You could try to fake a stretching background. I will edit the anwser with an example.

Comment: that just stretches all of the images on the page?

Comment: Give the img an id and in css use the #bgimg, see example above ^_^
In dom use getElementById().

Comment: okdoke, get you but the images are declared in the javascript, not in the html, will that effect it? I'd use a div instead I think for bg img, but not sure if I'm doing the javascript right.. something like... `code`document.getElementById(bgimg)body.background=processed[inc].src

Comment: Start with a base img and then switch later by js. But if you don't want to start with a base img but rather with an random img you could make use of window onLoad. Create a function for examle init() where you will randomly select an image and create the img element on the page(with the id bgimg).

Comment: ok got you, I have a base img anyway so that's fine but I just don't know how to specifically integrate the getelemnt in the javascript, I've tried but it just doesn't work at all. Not very good with javascript..

Comment: mmm hasn't helped much, tried to integrate with advice but it just won't work. :( anyone else know anything?